# Cannot access private member declared in class, even declared friend class

Tags: c++, class, private-members, friend-class

I have two classes:

```
class CALLDB;
class CALL
{
friend class CALLDB;
public:
    string GetStart()const;
private:
    string start;
};
```

And second class:

```
class CALLDB
{
friend class CALL;
public:
unsigned int Load(istream& fin);
private:
unsigned int numCalls;
};
```

In the main function, I did this:

```
int main(){
CALLDB calldata;
cout<<calldata.numCalls;
}
```

And then it says:

> error C2248: 'CALLDB::numCalls': cannot access private member declared in class 'CALLDB'

Why does it happen? Is something wrong with my friend class declaration?

Comment: `numCalls` is not friends with `main`...

Comment: You are trying to access ``calldata.numCalls`` from main so obviously it will result in compile-time error

Comment: oh thx, I see.. so if I don't make any change on those 2 classes, what should I do to the main?

Comment: If you don't change anything, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: You could add `friend int main();` into your CALLDB class declaration; that would allow your main() function to see its private member variable.  That said, a better approach would be to add a getter-method like `int getNumCalls() const {return numCalls;}` to your CALLDB class instead, and then main() can just call `calldata.getNumCalls();` instead of trying to access the private variable directly.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner damn THANKS dear sir! enlightened me like master Wugui

Answer (score 0):

friend class and functions are allowed to access the private data members of a class. so inside the class which is made as friend to another class,you can access the private member.to access the private members inside the friend class or friend function we have to create object for that class and then only we can access the private members.
   in your example you made CALLDB as friend to CALL and CALL to CALLDB so both the classes can access the private members of other class (i.e) you can access the private member of CALLDB in CALL and private member of CALL in CALLDB.but you tried to access the private members from main function which is not a friend to a class.I hope that you understand the concept.here i have given an simple example to understand the concept of friend class .you try that and do your program as per your requirement

```
#include <iostream>
Using namespace std;
class CALLDB;
class CALL
{
  friend class CALLDB;
  private:
    void display()
      {

       cout<<"\n from Private function of display() of the class CALL ";
     }
};

class CALLDB
  {
    friend class CALL;
    public:
       void output()
         {
           CALL ca;
           cout<<"\n from public function output of CALLDB class ";
           cout<<"\n Calling of private function display of class CALL";
           ca.display();
        }
  };

int main()
 {
    CALLDB cd1;
    cd1.output();
 }
```

OUTPUT

from public function output of CALLDB class
 Calling of private function display of class CALL
 from Private function of display() of the class CALL

Comment: appreciate your effort, it was so clear and accurate! problem solved!